# Base64.decode especifico

Tags: android

Estou tentando carregar uma string que recebo do WebService em uma ImageView do
Android.
Fiz algumas comparações e constatei que a string que recebo esta correta, porém é uma string e como tal não consigo carrega para a imageView.

Mas ao transforma-la para um Array de Bytes com

```
byte[] base64converted=   Base64.decode(lista.get(position).getImageData(),Base64.DEFAULT);
```

A string que era assim: `FFD8FFE000104A46 4946000101000001`, se torna isso: `1450FC145134D34D 74E00E3AE3DE3AD3`

Preciso que sejam os mesmos bytes. Que seja um objeto do tipo byte[], mas que tenha esse contéudo: `FFD8FFE000104A46...` e não esse `1450FC145134D34D...`

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
```

também não funciona, ela também altera os bytes da string o mesmo que string.getBytes() faz.

Qual método devo usar para conseguir isso: transformar uma string em byte[] sem
alterar o contéudo?

Comment: Um pouco confuso. Tenta isso: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18571348/2570426

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente cheguei à resposta.

Essa função resolveu a questão:

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Link da [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java) para maiores informações.